# Working in dev mode. See only the changes when restart server

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Coding in nuxtjs / macbook pro with custom build API.  Starting dev server on mac with

```
yarn dev
```

Changing the vue files. But I see only when I restart the server

Is this a config issue? Assume when change some basic template that changes are instant.

Comment: We don't have enough information here to be able to anwser properly. What is your "custom build API"? It sounds like it does have something to do with your problem.

Comment: Same problem here, Nuxt 3.6.5 with Nitro 2.6.3 on Node v18.17.1 in windows 10 wsl